# Accessing values in ViewModel in a dxList - PhoneJS

Tags: ios, web-applications, knockout.js, devexpress, phonejs

So in my PhoneJS web app, I have a dxList widget, with checkboxes on each item.  I want to be able to select multiple items, and then do something with them.  I'm trying to bind the 'checked' binding to an observable, but I get an 'undefined' error.

Here's the code for the dxTemplate for the list

```
<div data-options="dxTemplate:{name:'item'}">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.information"></span>
    <div data-bind="dxCheckBox: { checked: check_boxes }"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `check_boxes` is in the viewModel, not the `item` array.  I need to access values in the viewModel.  I've tried `viewModel.check_boxes`, but with no success.

Here's the js code:

```
AppNamespace.otherView = function (params) {
    var viewModel = {
        my_list: [
            {
                key: 'Group 1',
                items: [
                    { information: 'Test 1' },
                    { information: 'Test 2'},
                    { information: 'Test 3' }
                ]
            }
        ],
        check_boxes: ko.observable(false),
        //...etc
```

Has anyone had any experience with this, and is there a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout provides special properties to access parent binding contexts. In your case both `$parent` and `$root` should work.

More on this topic in Knockout docs: [Binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).